# Scene dark when perspective camera is far from scenery

Tags: unity, camera, lighting

I can't find anything about this subject in the docs or forums to know if this is normal behavior: There seems to be a direct correlation between how close to the scenery my camera gets and how brightly lit the scene is. My camera is able to move up to 200 units from Vector3.zero. Here are two shots of the same piece of scenery - one close up, one far away:

[image]

The camera is set to perspective, using deferred rendering.

Things I've tried:

- Turning off post processing
- Using auto expose in post processing
- Changing to orthographic (removes the issue, scene is uniformly bright at any distance)
- Changing the FOV
- Changing global lighting to use color rather than skybox
- Putting some lights at altitude

This may be normal behavior & I just havent noticed before. Can anyone confirm? Is there some way to prevent this happening? I don't want to use an orthographic camera but I do want the scene to be evenly bright at any distance from the camera.

Comment: Is the light attached to the camera?

Comment: No. There's one directional light at (0, 100, 0) and a bunch of point lights scattered around the scene. Changing the range on the point lights makes no difference to the problem.

Comment: Do you have fog enabled in your scene? How have you configured your materials?

Comment: @DMGregory - Yeah that was it, somehow the fog color got changed to pure black. Thanks.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please feel free to post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @DMGregory - Solution was yours, post & I'll happily accept

Comment: You have the context of your scene to use when illustrating the answer, so I think you can describe it in better detail.